# Ошибка линковщика при попытке подключить SDL2 на Linux + cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, c++17, sdl

Собрал и установил SDL 2 из исходников с официального сайта.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

После этого пытаюсь подключить его в своём cmake проекте, но линовщик даёт ошибку `unrecognized option '--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2'`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(sdl_test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Пробовал собирать при помощи gcc-11 и clang-13.

Ubuntu 21.10, gcc-11, clang-13, cmake 3.20 (пробовал генераторы make и ninja).

**upd**: после этого дополнительно поставил различные части sdl из репозиториев, это не помогло.
`sudo apt install libghc-sdl2-dev libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-net-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-dev`

**upd2**: Сборка проекта с `make VERBOSE=1`

```
make VERBOSE=1
/usr/local/bin/cmake -S/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test -B/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test/CMakeFiles /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test'
make  -f CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test'
cd /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test/CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test'
make  -f CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test'
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++  -I/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test/sdl_test -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable sdl_test
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/main.cpp.o -o sdl_test   -L/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test/sdl_test  -L"/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test/-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2"  -Wl,-rpath,"/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test/sdl_test:/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test/-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2" -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/build.make:97: sdl_test] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/sdl_test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/riv/mainProjects/cpp_test'
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Comment: а можно полный лог сборки (с `make VERBOSE=1`) и конфигурации посмотреть?

Comment: @Fat-Zer сборки проекта или SDL?

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
> ```

Эта строчка лишняя: ты пытаешься вместо *каталогов* с библиотеками для линковки подсунуть *флаги* линковки, что сильно смущает линкер. Указывать её не обязательно т.к. в config-модуле для `find_package()`, который идёт в комплекте с sdl2, `SDL2_LIBRARIES` уже включает путь до библиотек для линкера (флаг `-L...`), так что эту строчку можно просто опустить.

Если хочется явно указать путь до библиотек, то он задаётся в переменной `SDL2_LIBDIR`:

```
link_directories(${SDL2_LIBDIR})
```

Также, не ошибка, но в `link_directories` и `include_directories` не надо передавать каталог `${PROJECT_NAME}` (если такого каталога с инклюдами на самом деле нет).

Comment: т.е. функцию link_directories с SDL вызывать вообще не надо?

Comment: @Rivand, если кратко, то да, не обязательно... +добавил в ответ